# Custom labelling of equations in appendix section

Tags: numbering, counters, appendices

I spent some time looking at existing posts on this topic but I could not find anything that I was able to use. I am writing a LaTeX document with some sections and an appendix. I would like all the equations in the sections to be labeled (and cross-referenced) normally, using the `\label{somelabel}` inside `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` and then `\ref{somelabel}` when I want to reference it. So this will produce labels (1), (2), etc.

But I would like to use a separate counter for the equations in the appendix, and these equations should be labeled (A1), (A2), etc. So the printed output should look like:

Section 1
This is the first equation (1).
Using equation (A1), we find the second equation (2)

Section 2
This is the third equation (3), using equation (A2)

Appendix
This is the first appendix equation (A1). This is the second appendix equation (A2).

etc.

Comment: Does writing `\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand\theequation{A\arabic{equation}}` after `\apendix` solves your problem?

Comment: @Udi Fogiel Yes, it does! Thank you.

Comment: Which document class do you employ? And which command(s) do you employ to enter the appendix portion of the document? Does your document contain a single appendix section, or could it contain more than one appendix section? If the document contains, two appendix sections labelled "A" and "B", should any equations in Appendix B be labeled (B1), (B2), etc? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I am using documentclass{article} I am using \appendix to enter the appendix. My document contains only one appendix but it would be interesting to know ow to handle the situation with two appendices.

Comment: @ValerioDeAngelis - please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you add the instructions

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection\arabic{equation}}
```

immediately after `\appendix`. The former instruction tells LaTeX to reset the `equation` counter to zero each time `\section` is executed. The latter determines how equation numbers will be displayed -- here: by prefixing the section "number" (A, B, etc) before the plain equation number.

That way, equations in Appendix B will automatically be labeled "B1", "B2", etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-references

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\Cref{eq:aaa,eq:bbb}.
\Cref{eq:ccc,eq:ddd,eq:eee,eq:fff,eq:ggg,eq:hhh}.

\section{Hello World}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:aaa} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:bbb} 1+2=3 \end{equation}

\appendix  % label section numbers alphabetically: "A", "B", etc
\counterwithin*{equation}{section} % reset 'equation' counter whenever '\section' is executed
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection\arabic{equation}} % how to display the equation "number"

\section{Uno}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ccc} 2+2=4 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ddd} 2+3=5 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eee} 3+3=6 \end{equation}

\section{Due}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:fff} 3+4=7 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ggg} 4+4=8 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:hhh} 4+5=9 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Yes, your solution is more general. (I always think about how simple should be an answer to a basic question).

Answer (score 4):

A naive, but working version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{One}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\section{Two}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq4}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq5}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq6}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq4}, \eqref{eq7}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq7}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq8}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq9}
2+2=7
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq4}, \eqref{eq7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really do not want the dot between `A` and the number, you can write `\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}}`.

Comment: +1. You could combine `\renewcommand{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{0}` as `\counterwithin{equation}{section}`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the `section` Appendix for equation numbering after you declare the start of `\appendix`. Like this

```
\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Then all equations after that will be labeled `(A.1)`, `(A.2)` and so on.
This is neat since `\numberwithin` does not have to be put in the preamble.

Comment: You should also mention that (a) the `\numberwithin` macro is provided by the `amsmath` package and hence that it's necessary to load the `amsmath` package, and (b) that your proposed solution inserts a period between the section label and the equation number; this formatting aspect runs counter to the OP's stated formatting objective. A separate issue: Your claim that "This is neat since `\numberwithin` does not have to be put in the preamble" is somewhat confusing since, in fact, `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` should *not* be placed in the preamble for the use case at hand.